# How to prevent download of media(Videos, Photos) from a AWS s3 signed url?

Tags: android, python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to display photos and videos in my mobile/web app. I have used short lived signed urls to serve content privately. I want that a person should be able to only view the video in my apps and is not able to download the media even if he sniffs the signed url.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.
You can request the signed URL from your app or API side of your app each time users open your app.
Also, limit the URL to specify a time for example 20 seconds.
For more info please check the following URL

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html

Comment: I am already using signed urls(as mentioned in question). The issue is that even if the url is signed and valid for 20 sec, a user can easily sniff it using tools and open that signed url(in those 20 seconds) in browser and end up downloading the complete video.